# rpc error: code = unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I am facing the same issue as mentioned in [ErrImagePull: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73136370/21502622).

I copied the `ca.crt` to `/etc/docker/certs.d/my.harbor.com/` along with `my.harbor.cert` and `my.harbor.com.key`, and I also copied the `ca.crt` to `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/` and run command update-ca-certificates to update.

```
openssl s_client -connect my.harbor.com:443 -showcerts </dev/null
```

Output:

```
:140125490299328:error:2008F002:BIO routines:BIO_lookup_ex:system lib:../crypto/bio/b_addr.c:704:Name or service not known connect:errno=2
```

I am struggling from couple of days, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Issue resolved, created a new HTTPS certificate on the Harbor Host and copied ca.cert to /usr/local/share/ca-certificates. ran update-ca-certificates on all nodes (Master + Worker) restarted the server and ran the pod creation, it was successfull

Comment: Can you provide the detailed resolution steps you have followed and provide it as an answer for the greater visibility of the community.

Answer (score 0):

**To resolve your error :**(rpc error: code = unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image x509: certificate signed by unknown authority).

Create a new HTTPS certificate on the Harbor Host and copy `ca.cert` to `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates`. Run `update-ca-certificates` on all nodes (Master + Worker) restarted the server and run the pod creation.

**Note :** For greater visibility of the community I am posting @**Atul Mishra** comment as an answer.